# Free/Inexpensive tools for drawing/wireframing GUI interfaces?

Tags: gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software for designing prototypes (a raw design) of user interfaces](https://superuser.com/questions/33442/software-for-designing-prototypes-a-raw-design-of-user-interfaces)

I'm basically looking for a straightforward drawing application for Windows XP that allows me to easily create and resize GUI controls (such as buttons, radio buttons, menus, tabs, etc.).

Is there anything open source or inexpensive (hopefully less than $100) that can do this?

Comment: Is this to be implemented in any particular programming language?

Comment: @BlueNovember, sometimes, but I have tools for actually building "real" GUIs (e.g., Expression Blend or the designer in Visual Studio). The problem is, sometimes I just need to produce quick mockups, and the programming tools just aren't fast enough.

Comment: My first thought after seeing the title was "pencil and paper" :)

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/33442/software-for-designing-prototypes-a-raw-design-of-user-interfaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are simply looking to design a GUI, rather than implement a working prototype, then [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) may be useful.

Comment: Thx, +1. Checking it out now. Seems like it might be just what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Visio can do this, but Balsamiq (as suggested by sblair) looks like it's a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Visio is my favourite, but it is over £100.

For under, sblair has already mentioned [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups), but another nice one is [Pencils](http://www.evolus.vn/Pencil/Home.html).

[image]

Comment: Since this question is a duplicate of another one, I would recommend you to move your answer rather on the other one, to have all answers in one place, preferably.

Comment: Why -1? :S Anyway, Will post in other question.